# Rendering success or failure on the same page REMINDER HERE

Tags: php, html

My error or success message is not in the right place, so I want to know how to get my message in the right place.

I have been searching the internet. I cannot find the right solution.

Here a photo what I mean.

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php include('import_excel.php') ?>
<?php include('functions.php') ?>
<html lang="en" class=""><head>
  <meta name="ac:base" content="/C:/xampp/htdocs/Angular-421-N-WORK-APP">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>N-WORK-USER | opslag-Sorting</title>
  <meta name="description" content="app, web app, responsive, responsive layout, admin, admin panel, admin dashboard, flat, flat ui, ui kit, AngularJS, ui route, charts, widgets, components">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../libs/assets/animate.css/animate.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../libs/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../libs/assets/simple-line-icons/css/simple-line-icons.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../libs/jquery/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.min.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/component.css">
  <script>
          (function(e,t,n){
            var r=e.querySelectorAll("html")[0];r.className=r.className.replace(/(^|\s)no-js(\s|$)/,"$1js$2");
          }
           
        (document,window,0)
          );                         
  </script>
  
</head>
<body>
  <!-- content -->
  <div id="content" class="app-content" role="main">
    <div class="app-content-body ">

    <div ng-controller="FullcalendarCtrl">
    <!-- main header -->
  <div class="wrapper-md bg-yello b-b">    
    <h1 class="m-n font-thin h3">Lijst werkkracht TL GL Database</h1>
  </div>
    <!-- / main header -->
<div class="wrapper-md" ng-controller="FormDemoCtrl">
  <div class="panel panel-defaultgrd">
    <div class="panel-headinggrd font-bold text-blue">
      Uitslag
    </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
  <div class="hbox hbox-auto-xs hbox-auto-sm">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12 control-label">             
        <a href="form_werkkracht_database.php"><button class="btn btn-info">Database invoegen</button></a>
        <a class="btn btnx btn-orange" id="download-btn" target="_new"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Export to Excel</a>
       <form method="post" action="import_excel.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">      
       <div class="form-groupp" style="">            
        <input type="file" name="file-7" id="file-7" class="inputfile inputfile-6" data-multiple-caption="{count} files selected" multiple=""><label for="file-7"><span></span> <strong><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="17" viewBox="0 0 20 17"><path d="M10 0l-5.2 4.9h3.3v5.1h3.8v-5.1h3.3l-5.2-4.9zm9.3 11.5l-3.2-2.1h-2l3.4 2.6h-3.5c-.1 0-.2.1-.2.1l-.8 2.3h-6l-.8-2.2c-.1-.1-.1-.2-.2-.2h-3.6l3.4-2.6h-2l-3.2 2.1c-.4.3-.7 1-.6 1.5l.6 3.1c.1.5.7.9 1.2.9h16.3c.6 0 1.1-.4 1.3-.9l.6-3.1c.1-.5-.2-1.2-.7-1.5z"></path></svg> Import Excel..</strong></label>
        </div>
        <a class="btnl"><button class="btn btn-info" style="">Upload</button></a>
         </form>
        
         <div class="table-responsive">                 
      <table id="mytable" class="table table-bordred table-striped">                 
         <thead>
           <tr>
           <th>#</th>
           <th>MBU</th>
           <th>Zone</th>
           <th>Omschrijving</th>
           <th>TL</th>
           <th>GL</th>
           <th>Stand in lijn</th>
           <th>Station</th>
           <th>MBU nr</th>
           <th>WO stap</th>
           <th>LOG stap</th>
           <th>Q stap</th>
           <th>RA stand</th>           
           <th>Edit</th>
           <th>Delete</th>
           </tr>
         </thead>
       <tbody>         
<?php
      $fetchdata=new DB_con(); 
      $sql=$fetchdata->fetchdata();
      $cnt=1;
         while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
           
     {
?>          
       <tr>       
       <td><?php echo htmlentities($cnt);?></td>
       <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['MBU']);?></td>
       <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['zone']);?></td>
       <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['omschr']);?></td>
       <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['tl']);?></td>
       <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['gl']);?></td>
       <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['stand_in_lijn']);?></td>
       <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['station']);?></td>
       <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['MBU_nr']);?></td>
       <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['WO_stap']);?></td>
       <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['LOG_stap']);?></td>
       <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['Q_stap']);?></td>
       <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['RA_stand']);?></td>       
       <td><a href="updat_form_database_tl_gl.php?id=<?php echo htmlentities($row['id']);?>"><button class="btn btn-info btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button></a></td>

       <td><a href="app_opslag_database_tl_gl.php?del=<?php echo htmlentities($row['id']);?>"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" onclick="return confirm('Wil je bestand echt verwijderen?');"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button></a></td>
    </tr>
<?php 
// for serial number increment
     $cnt++;
   } 
?>
       </tbody>      
     </table>
      </div>
        </div>
          </div>
            </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
  <!-- / main --> 
</div>  
  </div>      
  <!-- /content -->
  
  <!-- footer -->
  <footer id="footer" class="app-footer" role="footer">
    <div class="wrapper b-t bg-light">
      <span class="pull-right">2.3.0 <a href="#" ui-scroll="app" class="m-l-sm text-muted"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-up"></i></a></span>
      © 2018 Copyright.
    </div>
  </footer>
  <!-- / footer --> 
<script src="js/app.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

my other code import_excel.php

```
<?php
/**
 * RaeCreated by Homensdigiworld.
 * Admin: Stefaan
 * Date: 26-03-2019
 */
include_once "app_opslag_database_tl_gl.php";
use Box\Spout\Reader\ReaderFactory;
use Box\Spout\Common\Type;

require_once ('connect.php');
require_once ('Spout/Autoloader/autoload.php');

if(!empty($_FILES['file-7']['name']))
{
    // Get File extension eg. 'xlsx' to check file is excel sheet
    $pathinfo = pathinfo($_FILES['file-7']['name']);

    // check file has extension xlsx, xls and also check
    // file is not empty
    if (($pathinfo['extension'] == 'xlsx' || $pathinfo['extension'] == 'xls')
        && $_FILES['file-7']['size'] > 0 )
    {
        $file = $_FILES['file-7']['tmp_name'];

        // Read excel file by using ReadFactory object.
        $reader = ReaderFactory::create(Type::XLSX);

        // Open file
        $reader->open($file);
        $count = 0;

        // Number of sheet in excel file
        foreach ($reader->getSheetIterator() as $sheet)
        {

            // Number of Rows in Excel sheet
            foreach ($sheet->getRowIterator() as $row)
            {

                // It reads data after header. In the my excel sheet,
                // header is in the first row.
                if ($count > 0) {

                    // Data of excel sheet
                    $MBU = $row[1];
                    $zone = $row[2];
                    $omschr = $row[3];
                    $tl = $row[4];
                    $gl = $row[5];
                    $stand_in_lijn = $row[6];
                    $station = $row[7];
                    $MBU_nr = $row[8];
                    $WO_stap = $row[9];
                    $LOG_stap = $row[10];
                    $Q_stap = $row[11];
                    $RA_stand = $row[12];

                    //Here, You can insert data into database.
                    $qry = "INSERT INTO `users`(`MBU`, `zone`, `omschr`, `tl`, `gl`, `stand_in_lijn`, `station`, `MBU_nr`, `WO_stap`, `LOG_stap`, `Q_stap`, `RA_stand`) VALUES ('$MBU','$zone','$omschr','$tl','$gl','$stand_in_lijn','$station','$MBU_nr','$WO_stap','$LOG_stap','$Q_stap','$RA_stand')";
                    $res = mysqli_query($con,$qry);

                }
                $count++;
            }
        }

        if($res)
        {
            
            echo "Your file Uploaded Successfull";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Your file Uploaded Failed";
        }

        // Close excel file
        $reader->close();
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Please Choose only Excel file";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "File is Empty"."<br>";
    echo "Please Choose Excel file";
}

?>
```

I have that message : Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\xampp\htdocs\import-excel_08\index.php on line 29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are including the upload file at the top of your main page file.

`<?php include('import_excel.php') ?>`

It doesn't need to be included as it does nothing on that page, your form submits to that file.

Remove it from the top of that page and the message should go away.

Comment: I think you do not understand me I want that error or success message must be there see photo.@hawkyhawk14

Comment: I do understand, but currently you are importing a file, that checks for a POST. Because it is included there is no POST at that time (of the page load) and is defaulting to echoing out the errors. Because the file is included and not called as a function call, it is just dumping its output at the bottom of the page. 


You should really consider rewriting your code to split up page view code and PHP logic, as its just a mess and very hard to read.

Comment: Currently your code will never show a success message on the page you want after uploading a file.The form goes off to the uploader, and will just show a success message on a blank page.

Comment: that's right but I want it to come to this page effectively otherwise you can show an example if you want. And there is a POST present.

Comment: I would recommend for the code you have currently. Remove the include as mentioned above. In the " import_excel.php" file, instead of echo, assign the text to a session variable. Such as `$_SESSION["upload_message"] = "File uploaded okay";`. Also make sure the upload file redirects the person back to the first page. You can then echo the `$_SESSION["upload_message"]` on the first page.

Comment: I did so right. But is it normal that I already receive a message that I am not pushing the button yet?  @hawkyhawk14

Comment: if($res)
        {
   
            $_SESSION["upload_message"] = "File uploaded okay";
        }
        else
        {
            $_SESSION["upload_message"] = "Your file Uploaded Failed";
        }

        // Close excel file
        $reader->close();
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION["upload_message"] = "Please Choose only Excel file";
    }
}
else
{
    $_SESSION["upload_message"] = "File is Empty"."<br>";
    $_SESSION["upload_message"] = "Please Choose Excel file";
} - @hawkyhawk14

Comment: I have that message : Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\xampp\htdocs\import-excel_08\index.php on line 29 - @hawkyhawk14